# Pass all variables in Python namespace/scope to function without arguments

Tags: python, scope, namespaces, local-variables, keyword-argument

I want to pass the local scope/namespace of variables from within one function to a second one, without defining which named/keyword arguments this second function must expect, but I don't know what I am missing to be able to call the variables in this second function.

Functions definition:

```py
def first_f(holaaa):
    second_f(**locals())

def second_f(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    print(holaaa)
```

Call and outcome:

```py
first_f("adiooos")
```

```py
{'holaaa': 'adiooos'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_14659/552341488.py in <module>
      7     print(holaaa)
      8 
----> 9 first_f("adiooos")

/tmp/ipykernel_14659/552341488.py in first_f(holaaa)
      1 def first_f(holaaa):
----> 2     second_f(**locals())
      3 
      4 
      5 def second_f(**kwargs):

/tmp/ipykernel_14659/552341488.py in second_f(**kwargs)
      5 def second_f(**kwargs):
      6     print(kwargs)
----> 7     print(holaaa)
      8 
      9 first_f("adiooos")

NameError: name 'holaaa' is not defined
```

Comment: `kwargs['holaaa']` will work, just plainly referring to the variable without defining it won't.

Comment: More fundamentally, how could you ever write `holaaa` in your function body, when the creation of that variable is entirely dependent on the caller of the function? You have no idea whether `holaaa` will exist within your function, so you'd need to guard against `NameError`s all the time. Which is why this is somewhere between non-obvious and impossible to do, because it's a bad idea.

Comment: @deceze Thank you for your immediate answer. I don't think I understand your last comment, because `holaaa` is always going to exist in the first function, whatever its content is, as it's the name of the positional argument, right? Also, regarding your first comment, there is absolutely no way of defining the variables inside kwargs once the second function is being executed? I've played around with exec() but it hasn't seemed to work either.

Comment: *"`holaaa` is always going to exist in the first function"* — Yes, but not in the second. Just looking at the definition of `second_f`, `holaaa` isn't defined anywhere and is *not* guaranteed to exist. You can call `second_f` from anywhere, and nothing guarantees the existence of `holaaa` then. If you're only going to call `second_f` from `first_f`, then you don't need to define them as separate functions.

Comment: kwargs.get('holaaa', None)